# Making a macro runs automatically in Outlook

Tags: vba, outlook

I wrote a macro in VBA that does an action on some of the files that arrive to my inbox in Outlook. However, I will have to click a button or a shortkey to run this macro. Is there a way that this macro runs automatically whenever an email arrives to my inbox? 
Please help,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this contains an answer to your question:
http://www.ureader.com/msg/1081942.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You should be able use an Outlook rule to run a script. Have a look at "Rules and Alerts" and creating custom rules.

Comment: Alright. will try that. does that also cover moving/copying an email to a subfolder ? for example, if an email arrives with a subject "AAA", it should be copied/moved to a subfolder called "Test".This subfolder is a subfolder of inbox. how to do it? Thanks again for the quick response.

Comment: Yes you can use a rule to move messages to different folders.